# Including math symbols/equations in Doxygen markdown?

Tags: doxygen, mathjax

What is the best way to include math symbols/equations in Doxygen Markdown? I've gotten it to work by enabling MathJax in my Doxygen config doing something like this in my .md markdown file:

```
\\[
A_{C \\rightarrow P}=\\begin{bmatrix}
f * S_x / d_{px} & 0.0        & C_x & 0.0 \\\\ \
0.0              & f / d_{py} & C_y & 0.0 \\\\ \
0.0              & 0.0        & f   & 0.0 \\\\ \
0.0              & 0.0        & 1.0 & 0.0 \\\\
\\end{bmatrix}
\\]
```

But as you can see, I've entered the land of escaping hell. The original LaTeX used with a MathJax-enabled page looked like this:

```
\[
A_{C \rightarrow P}=\begin{bmatrix}
f * S_x / d_{px} & 0.0        & C_x & 0.0 \\
0.0              & f / d_{py} & C_y & 0.0 \\
0.0              & 0.0        & f   & 0.0 \\
0.0              & 0.0        & 1.0 & 0.0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you have a look at the doxygen commands \f{ etc, they can be used in doxygen's implementation for Markdown as well (see manual chapter about formulas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert) pointed it out, you just need to use [doxygen's formatting commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html), in your case `\f[` and `\f]`:

```
\f[
A_{C \rightarrow P}=\begin{bmatrix}
f * S_x / d_{px} & 0.0        & C_x & 0.0 \\
0.0              & f / d_{py} & C_y & 0.0 \\
0.0              & 0.0        & f   & 0.0 \\
0.0              & 0.0        & 1.0 & 0.0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\f]
```

---

It might not be relevant to your case, but it took me a while to realize that the default URL for MathJax provided by doxygen is invalid. One should [change it](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#mathjax-cdn), or include it in another way.